# how to create sqlite database in windows store app located at a specific folder

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Need help, I can't seem to access any other .sqlite database if its not located in the apps localfolder. Every tutorial I look at they always use

```
Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Example.sqlite");
```

I tried this:

```
const string testing = @"C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Packages\*************\LocalState";

            this.DBPath = Path.Combine(testing, "Example.sqlite");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
            {
                db.CreateTable<Customer>();

            }
```

and it worked. but when I change it to:

```
const string testing = @"C:\Databases";
```

It can't open the database even if I copied the database from the local folder of the app. 
Any suggestions ? I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in Cignal.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not open database file: D:\Databases\Example.sqlite (CannotOpen)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the C: drive for windows store apps. It's part of the store's sandbox. Each app is limited to which files and folders can be viewed. If you have a local database file you need to access, define the file as content in your app and access it using the path "ms-appx:///..."

Answer (score 0):

use file picker to select which folder you want to save the db file.
refer this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1